# Bokeh: How to change y axis scale from subunits of integers to just integers (i.e. 1, 2, 3)

Tags: python, django, bokeh

[The improperly formatted y axis graph units](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTQ4w.png)

Here is the attendant python code in my Django app views.py

```
plot2 = figure(title= title2,
               x_axis_label= 'Date',
               x_axis_type= 'datetime',
               y_axis_label= 'Ease of Sleep',
               y_axis_type='linear',
               plot_width =400,
               plot_height=400)

plot1.scatter(chart_values_x_graph1, 
              chart_values_y_graph1, 
              legend= 'f(x)', 
              line_width = 2)

script1, div1 = components(plot1, CDN)

plot2.scatter(chart_values_x_graph2, 
              chart_values_y_graph2, 
              legend='1 = Easily; 2 = After Some Time; 3 = With Difficulty', 
              line_width = 2)

script2, div2 = components(plot2, CDN)
```

Comment: Your image link is not correctly formatted. It's stuck in the code formatting.

Comment: I've edited your question to make sense. However, it is still very broad. The answer is "there are a few possible ways" depending on some details you have not included. SO is not very good for "collaborative back-and-forth" so I'd instead suggest you come to the [project mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!forum/bokeh) where we can discuss your situation in more detail. Then you can post your own answer here when we find the right one for your particular use-case.